# How to change admin password on Influx2?

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

I have an influxdb2 database running in kubernetes.

I can login to the web interface as admin
I can also access the pod running influx2 and run the influx command.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the admin password.
There appears to be no way to do it via the web interface.
I haven't been able to find a way to authenticate on the CLI

Can someone assist?

From the CLI I get:

```bash
$ influx user password -n admin
Error: failed to find user "admin": 401 Unauthorized: unauthorized access
```

Comment: Can you login into the influxdb web interface? Also what version of influxdb are you running?